# how to get a transparent table view

Tags: ios, uitableview

Can we make the table view transparent so that the image placed back to the table view is visible?

I want the table cells to look transparent.

Comment: You mentioned "in xcode". Do you mean you want to do it in built-in Interface Builder? or in coding? FYI, If transparent, the color of the underlying layer will reveal.

Comment: Choose background colour clearcolor

Comment: in coding.i have an image back of my table view. I want to make it visible.For that i want to make the white table cells to be transparent....

Comment: @Dolo By doing that only the background color is changing.but i want the table cell color to be clear..so that my background picture will be visible even through the cells....thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the certain UI element to be transparent in code, you can set the `backgroundColor` to `[UIColor clearColor]`.

You can implement it when creating the cell at:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
  if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
  }
  cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. If you find it useful, please upvote as well. (click the up arrow)

Comment: Sorry,I am a new user,not having enough reputation to vote...